# Axios + Microsoft Translate API Strange symbols in response

Tags: javascript, encoding, axios, rapidapi

I'm trying to get list of languages using Microsoft Translate Free Api from rapidapi.com. But in response I receive hundreds og these strange charachters:

```
����: example
```

Here is my axios config:

```
const axios = Axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://text-translator2.p.rapidapi.com",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept-Language": "en",
    "Accept-Encoding": "null",
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": ".../.../...",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "microsoft-translator-text.p.rapidapi.com",
  },
  params: { "api-version": "3.0" },
});
```

Maybe someone knows how to solve this problem?

 API link: https://rapidapi.com/microsoft-azure-org-microsoft-cognitive-services/api/microsoft-translator-text

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that pops out to me is the `Accept-Encoding: null` if you don't tell the server how you want it encoding I have no idea what it would do, maybe try filling that value with something from the following: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding ?